# How to remove duplicate combinations tuples from python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates, set

I have a list with tuples as below:

```
mylist = [(1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 1),(2, 3),(3, 1),(3, 2),(3, 3)]
```

Expected (Unique combinations)

```
[(1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 3),(3, 3)]
```

I tried below

```
mylist = list(set(map(tuple, mylist)))
```

But didnt get the desired output. Any help here?

Comment: What result *did* you get?

Comment: Your output is ```[(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2), (1, 3)]``` and that's correct. You did not consider ```(2,1)``` but it is not a duplicate and is different from ```(1,2)```

Comment: How did you get `mylist` from the first place?

Comment: Not producing duplicates in the first place is better than explicitly removing them afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
out=list(set(map(tuple,map(sorted,mylist))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because a `Tuple` `(1, 2)` is different from a `Tuple` `(2, 1)`

```
print((1, 2) == (1, 2))
print((1, 2) == (2, 1))

True
False
```

You can see it in:

```
my_set = set()

my_set.add((1, 2))
my_set.add((1, 2))
my_set.add((2, 1))

print(my_set)

{(1, 2), (2, 1)}
```

So, in your case, you can sort your `tuples`, so both `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` will be the same, and the set will get your job done

```
mylist = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]

mylist = [sorted(item) for item in mylist]

mylist = list(set(map(tuple, mylist)))

print(mylist)

[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```